# Blob upload to s3 with cropme.js

Tags: php, amazon-s3, vuejs2

I really need some help with this. I have never used blob as a resource before but I need to use cropme.js and it only outputs the file uploaded as a blob or base64. Here is the github repo for it: https://github.com/shpontex/cropme. I have it working 100% on my side and it gives me the output but I do not know how to go from here. I have tried to upload the blob as a file to Amazon S3 but all it does is save the file to S3 without an extension and when you try to open it, it is a the blob link. Which is useless because the blob will be removed once the browser is cleared. Uploading the base64 route does the same. I just need some direction here please.

Here is the function in app.js from cropme that gives the result:

```
        let img = document.getElementById('cropme-result')
        this.position = this.cropme.position()
        this.cropme.crop({
          type: 'blob', <-- here you can set it to either 'blob' or 'base64'
          width: 600
        }).then(function(res) {
          img.src = res
          document.getElementById('croppedimage').src = img.src
        })
      },
```

Here is part of the code which uploads the file to S3:

```
try {

$imagecropped = $_POST['image'];


    $key = 'photos/random';



        // S3 details
        $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'version'     => 'latest',
            'region'      => 'us-west-2',
            'credentials' => [                
                'key'    => 'MYKEY',
                'secret' => 'MYSECRET',
            ],
        ]);

        $result = $s3Client->putObject([
            'Bucket' => 'uploads',
            'ACL' => 'public-read',
            'Key' => $key,
            'Body' => $imagecropped,
        ]);
```

Comment: are you doing the putObject clientside? show your code

Comment: yes, I have added it in

Comment: you need put the blob in a form object and post as multitype then access in $_FILES, or use base64 one and access in $_POST or php://input depending on how you post it ajax etc. I making something similar but direct to s3 [*](https://github.com/lcherone/S3-Manager)

Comment: It gets posted via ajax when the user clicks a button on the site. I would really appreciate an example.